# new blank jira plugin throws exception as soon as i edit jira.version in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I wanted to try develop a jira extension. I followed the tutorial and all went fine. It sets the *'jira.version'* automatically to **6.4.4**, which ran totally fine, but I want it to be **6.3.14**. So I edited the pom.xml and ran `atlas-clean`, `atlas-mvn package` and `atlas-run`. But no luck. As soon as I try to access the jira URL with my browser I get

> com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Cannot construct Factory : com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory: com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not parse config file : /WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

I even tried creating a completely fresh plugin and edited the pom directly after it was created and before every other `atlas-` command.

So what did I miss or what did I do wrong? Why is it working with *'jira.version'* set to 6.4.4, but not set to 6.3.14? I really did not edit anything besides the *'jira.version'* parameter at the automatically created **pom.xml**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your encoding, or some invisible character is present at the very beginning of your file.

Comment: But as soon as I change it back from 6.3.14 to 6.4.4 or even 6.4.6 it works again. As I said, I didn't edit the "vanilla pom" besides the *'jira.version'*. And when my editor (doesn't matter whether it's Notepad++ or Netbeans) would "destroy" the pom, it shouldn't work either when changing the version back again - but it does.

Comment: Where does this `/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml` file come from? Is it yours or from your dependency? Maybe some versions do have that file "wrong".

Comment: I don't know where this `sitemesh.xml`. As I said, I followd the official atlassien-plugin-sdk tutorial instructions and created the basic empty skeletton. All files created are those of the create and run commands itself. May it be possible to be some compatibility issue with jdk 1.8 or default tomcat?